# Как сделать border как на картинке?

Tags: css, border

Решил сделать такой "каталог" и сделать его резиновым. Выровнял столбцы `display:inline-block`, но появились отступы между этими ячейками, чтобы убрать их, задал `margin-left:-2%`; все сомкнулось в единое целое и border не разрывался, но пропал текст верхней строки. Подскажите, как сделать такой border:
[image: Как должно получиться]

CSS:

```
.figure {
    width:20%;
    height:35%; 
    border-radius:none;
    font-style:italic;
    padding:1em 2em;
    text-align:center;
}
.figure img {
    width:90%;
    height:100%;
}
.figure p {
    padding-top:2%;
}
#gallery {
    border-bottom:1px solid #000;
    width:100%;
    height:50%;
    margin-bottom:5%;
}
#gallery .figure {
    display:inline-block;
    float:none;
}
```

HTML:

```
<article id='gallery' align="center">
    <div class='figure'>
      <p><a href='images/komod.png'><img id='hall' src='images/komod.png' alt='Комод' /></a></p>
      <p><a href='hall.html'>Шкафы Купе</a></p>
    </div>
     <div class='figure'>
        <p><a href='images/komod.png'><img id='hall' src='images/pr.png' alt='Комод' /></a></p>
      <p><a href='hall.html'>Шкафы Купе</a></p>
    </div>
     <div class='figure'>
        <p><a href='images/komod.png'><img id='hall' src='images/sh.png' alt='Комод' /></a></p>
      <p><a href='hall.html'>Шкафы Купе</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class='figure'>
      <p><a href='images/lotus.jpg'><img id='hall' src='images/komod.png' alt='Храм Лотоса' /></a></p>
      <p><a href='lotus.html'>Кухонные гарнитуры </a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="gall">
    <div class='figure'>
      <p><a href='images/arctic.jpg'><img id='hall' src='images/komod.png' alt='Арктичний собор' /></a></p>
      <p><a href='history.html#arctic'>Журнальные столики </a></p>
    </div>
    <div class='figure'>
      <p><a href='images/familia.jpg'><img  id='hall' src='images/familia.jpg' alt='Саґрада Фамілія' /></a></p>
      <p><a href='familia.html'>Обеденные столы </a></p>
    </div>
    <div class='figure'>
      <p><a href='images/vasyl.jpg'><img id='hall' src='images/vasyl.jpg' alt='Собор Василя Блаженного' /></a></p>
      <p><a href='history.html#vasyl'> Прихожие и гардеробные </a></p>
    </div>
    <div class='figure'>
      <p><a href='images/minimal.jpg'><img  id='hall' src='images/minimal.jpg' alt='Церква розради' /></a></p>
      <p><a href='history.html#minimal'>Письменные столы</a></p>
    </div>
    </div>
  </article>*/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вроде бы похоже если что то не так пишите:найдём нужное решение

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.clear,
.clear:after,
.clear:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
section {
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
  min-height: 90%;
  margin: 10px auto;
  background: #fefefe;
  text-align: center;
}
section .post {
  width: 30%;
  min-height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #ddd;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 10px 0;
}
section .post p {
  font-size: 2.5vh;
}
section .post h3 {
  font-size: 4vh;
  padding: 5px 0;
}
.post-img {
  width: 60%;
  margin: 3px auto;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 680px) {
  section {
    height: auto;
  }
  .post {
    min-width: 47%;
    max-width: 47%;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .post .post-img {
    width: 60%;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  section {
    height: auto;
  }
  .post {
    min-width: 90%;
    max-width: 90%;
    min-height: 240px;
  }
  .post-img {
    width: 60%;
    height: 120px;
  }
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="post">
    <div class="post-img">
      <img src="http://www.fainaidea.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/fMP3DLd03cw.jpg" alt="post-image">
    </div>
    <div class="post-article">
      <h3>Нижнее бельё: Gractio</h3>
      <p>При покупке современного нижнего белья, следует быть не только внимательным, но также понимающим – потому что существует много способов преодолеть плохой..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--post...image -->
  <div class="post">
    <div class="post-img">
      <img src="http://st3-fashiony.ru/pic/photo/pic/77741/18.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="post-article">
      <h3>Нижнее бельё: Gractio</h3>
      <p>При покупке современного нижнего белья, следует быть не только внимательным, но также понимающим – потому что существует много способов преодолеть плохой..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--post...image -->
  <div class="post">
    <div class="post-img">
      <img src="http://vostorgopt.ru/data/images/content/leilieve10.jpg" alt="post-image">
    </div>
    <div class="post-article">
      <h3>Нижнее бельё: Gractio</h3>
      <p>При покупке современного нижнего белья, следует быть не только внимательным, но также понимающим – потому что существует много способов преодолеть плохой..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--post...image -->
  <div class="post">
    <div class="post-img">
      <img src="http://katyaburg.ru/sites/default/files/pictures/obuv_acsessuary/genskoe_modnoe_nignee_belje_15.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="post-article">
      <h3>Нижнее бельё: Gractio</h3>
      <p>При покупке современного нижнего белья, следует быть не только внимательным, но также понимающим – потому что существует много способов преодолеть плохой..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--post...image -->
  <div class="post">
    <div class="post-img">
      <img src="http://img1.liveinternet.ru/images/attach/c/9/107/339/107339919_2.jpg" alt="post-image">
    </div>
    <div class="post-article">
      <h3>Нижнее бельё: Gractio</h3>
      <p>При покупке современного нижнего белья, следует быть не только внимательным, но также понимающим – потому что существует много способов преодолеть плохой..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--post...image -->
  <div class="post">
    <div class="post-img">
      <img src="http://c-miel.ru/images/zhen-nizh-bel-1.jpg" alt="post-image">
    </div>
    <div class="post-article">
      <h3>Нижнее бельё: Gractio</h3>
      <p>При покупке современного нижнего белья, следует быть не только внимательным, но также понимающим – потому что существует много способов преодолеть плохой..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--post...image -->

  <div class="post">
    <div class="post-img">
      <img src="http://stelari.ru/uploads/posts/2014-04/1396854059_5.png" alt="post-image">
    </div>
    <div class="post-article">
      <h3>Нижнее бельё: Gractio</h3>
      <p>При покупке современного нижнего белья, следует быть не только внимательным, но также понимающим – потому что существует много способов преодолеть плохой..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--post...image -->
</section>
```

> http://codepen.io/Geyan/pen/ozjqAG?editors=110

чуть чуть переделаете его и "**дело в шляпе**"